# Export mysql table data as xlsx format using phpspreadsheet,can't not importing

Tags: php, mysql

I used phpspreadsheet to export mysql table data as XLSX format but after exporting when I import the XLSX file its not importing.the exported xlsx file data is ok.If I copy the data in another XLSX file then it works perfectly.
Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Program');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'FormalCode');
$sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Title');

$sql = "select * from class_routine";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $n = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $rowNum = $n + 1;
        $sheet->setCellValue('A' .$rowNum, $row['Program']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('B' .$rowNum, $row['FormalCode']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('C' .$rowNum, $row['Title']);
$n++;
        
        
    }
}

$filename = 'ClassRoutine-template-'.time().'.xlsx';
// Redirect output to a client's web browser (Xlsx)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
 
// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Full Code Here https://pastebin.com/imP2QdLm

Giving this warnings when importing the exported xlsx file in import page:

> Warning: XMLReader::open(): Empty string supplied as input in C:\xampp\htdocs\corap\vendor\SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php on line 959
>
> Warning: XMLReader::read(): Load Data before trying to read in C:\xampp\htdocs\corap\vendor\SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php on line 995
>
> Warning: XMLReader::read(): Load Data before trying to read in C:\xampp\htdocs\corap\vendor\SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php on line 995

Comment: Can you open the created xlsx file with Excel without it giving any errors?

Comment: Yes,there is no error opening xlsx file!

Comment: Giving this warnings when importing the exported xlsx file in import page:

Warning: XMLReader::open(): Empty string supplied as input in C:\xampp\htdocs\corap\vendor\SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php on line 959

Warning: XMLReader::read(): Load Data before trying to read in C:\xampp\htdocs\corap\vendor\SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php on line 995

Warning: XMLReader::read(): Load Data before trying to read in C:\xampp\htdocs\corap\vendor\SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php on line 995

[import code:] (https://pastebin.com/s5TYDc2C) @RiggsFolly